# Sum Amounts That Fall Within Variable Date Ranges

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables similar to the example tables below. The `PAY` table shows how much an employee was paid and when. The `ENROLL` table shows when an employee was enrolled `'E'` and when they later terminated `'T'`. So, in this case, the employee was enrolled from `3/1/14` to `5/31/14` and then enrolled again from `10/01/14` to `11/30/14`.

#### PAY table

```
EMPLID      PAY_END_DT    PAY_AMT
00100001    31-JAN-14     110
00100001    28-FEB-14     120
00100001    31-MAR-14     130     <-- should be included in SUM
00100001    30-APR-14     140     <-- should be included in SUM
00100001    31-MAY-14     150     <-- should be included in SUM
00100001    30-JUN-14     160
00100001    31-JUL-14     170
00100001    31-AUG-14     180
00100001    30-SEP-14     190
00100001    31-OCT-14     200     <-- should be included in SUM
00100001    30-NOV-14     210     <-- should be included in SUM
00100001    31-DEC-14     220
```

#### ENROLL table

```
EMPLID      EFFDT       STATUS
00100001    01-MAR-14   E
00100001    31-MAY-14   T
00100001    01-OCT-14   E
00100001    30-NOV-14   T
```

What I want is a SQL that will sum the `PAY_AMT` column but only for the `PAY_AMT`s that have `PAY_END_DT`s that occur while the employee was enrolled. For instance, in this case, I only want to sum the `PAY_AMT`s that have `PAY_END_DT`s that fall either within `3/1/14` to `5/31/14` or `10/01/14` to `11/30/14`. So, the correct result would be:

```
EMPLID    SUM
00100001  830
```

I would need to run this SQL for a lot of different `EMPLID`s where some may have two enrollment periods like this example and others may have zero, one, three or more enrollment periods.

I had thought about using `lead()` but can't quite figure out how to use it in this case. I had also thought about using `between...and...` but since the number of enrollment periods can vary, I don't know how to handle that.

I would prefer not to use PL/SQL.

To make things a little easier, a template for these two tables is below:

```
WITH 
PAY AS(
SELECT '00100001' AS EMPLID, TO_DATE('2014-01-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS PAY_END_DT, 110.00 AS PAY_AMT FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '00100001', TO_DATE('2014-02-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 120.00 AS PAY_AMT FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
--SUM column would include this PAY_AMT
SELECT '00100001', TO_DATE('2014-03-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 130.00 AS PAY_AMT FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
--SUM column would include this PAY_AMT
SELECT '00100001', TO_DATE('2014-04-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 140.00 AS PAY_AMT FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
--SUM column would include this PAY_AMT
SELECT '00100001', TO_DATE('2014-05-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 150.00 AS PAY_AMT FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '00100001', TO_DATE('2014-06-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 160.00 AS PAY_AMT FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '00100001', TO_DATE('2014-07-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 170.00 AS PAY_AMT FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '00100001', TO_DATE('2014-08-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 180.00 AS PAY_AMT FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '00100001', TO_DATE('2014-09-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 190.00 AS PAY_AMT FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
--SUM column would include this PAY_AMT
SELECT '00100001', TO_DATE('2014-10-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 200.00 AS PAY_AMT FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
--SUM column would include this PAY_AMT
SELECT '00100001', TO_DATE('2014-11-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 210.00 AS PAY_AMT FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '00100001', TO_DATE('2014-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 220.00 AS PAY_AMT FROM DUAL
),
ENROLL AS (
SELECT '00100001' AS EMPLID, TO_DATE('2014-03-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS EFFDT, 'E' AS STATUS FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '00100001', TO_DATE('2014-05-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'T' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '00100001', TO_DATE('2014-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'E' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '00100001', TO_DATE('2014-11-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'T' FROM DUAL
)
```

Comment: Can you _flatten_ the `ENROLL` table? It would then be much easier to accomplish what you're trying to do. Otherwise you'll get yourself into some crazy OLAP queries, and you really shouldn't.

Comment: Can you have an open-ended enrolment period?

Comment: npe - I'm not familiar with flattening tables, but if that would help I'm all for it.  Alex Poole - Well the SQL would sum amounts that fell between 01/01/2014 and 12/31/2014 so if the person had enrolled effective 10/01/2014, for instance, then it is possible that they may not have a termination row on the Enroll table yet. So, I think the answer is yes, you can have an open ended enrollment period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess about `lead()` is correct, and solution is quite simple:

```
with pay as (...),
     enroll as (...)
select pay.emplid, sum(pay_amt) 
    from pay, 
         (select emplid, effdt effdt_start, status, 
                 lead(effdt, 1) over (partition by emplid order by effdt) effdt_end
            from enroll) enr
   where enr.emplid = pay.emplid
     and enr.status = 'E'
     and pay.pay_end_dt between enr.effdt_start and enr.effdt_end
   group by pay.emplid;
```

Comment: That's pretty straightforward, I think that will work.

Comment: @BarrettNashville Sorry, forgot to say: my solution works only on closed periods, when periods don't intersect and when count of rows with `E` is equal to count of `T`. In a case when you have one opened period (the latest) you can "close" it manually by `nvl(lead(...), <date in far future>)`.